# Cancel an Async Task C#

Tags: c#

I want the user to be able to cancel/abort a task that is called by an async button. I've had a look at CancellationTokens but I don't really understand how to implement it.

### 'Download' button:

```
private async void dlSelected_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (dlDataGrid.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                object item = dlDataGrid.SelectedItem;
                string name = (dlDataGrid.SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text;
                string dl = (dlDataGrid.SelectedCells[2].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text;

                dlSelected.IsEnabled = false;
                refreshList.IsEnabled = false;
                dlPRing.IsActive = true;

                await DownloadFile2(name, dl, "./Data/Downloads/" + name);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

### 'Download' Task:

```
private async Task DownloadFile2(string name, string url, string path)
    {

        //Set status label
        tbDLStatus.Text = "Downloading File...";

        var DLclient = new WebClient();
        DLclient.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            //Set names for each property
            tbDLPercent.Text = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";
            tbFileName.Text = name;
            tbDir.Text = path;

            double progress = 0;
            if (e.ProgressPercentage > progress)
            {
                //Change value of progressbar to download
                pbProgress.Value = (e.ProgressPercentage / 100.0d);
                progress = e.ProgressPercentage;
            }
        };

        DLclient.DownloadFileCompleted += async (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                //Delete the file
                if (File.Exists(path))
                {
                    File.Delete(path);
                }
            }
            else if (e.Error != null)
            {
                await this.ShowMessageAsync("Error!", "An error occured while attempting to download " + name + "! \n\nPlease check your internet connection and try again in a few minutes.",
                   MessageDialogStyle.Affirmative);

                //Delete the file
                if (File.Exists(path))
                {
                    File.Delete(path);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Set for completed DL successfully.
                if (cbAutoRun.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Process.Start(tbDir.Text);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                    }
                }

                //Allow open file/folder
                btnOpen.IsEnabled = true;
                btnOpenFolder.IsEnabled = true;
            }

            dlSelected.IsEnabled = true;
            pbProgress.Value = 0;
            tbDLStatus.Text = "Finished Downloading";
            dlPRing.IsActive = false;
        };

        await DLclient.DownloadFileTaskAsync((url), path);
        DLclient.Dispose();
    }
```

So my question is, if I were in the process of downloading a large file and I want to cancel it via a button, how would I do so?

Thanks,

Comment: Cancel Async Task from a button: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21115961/4945059

Comment: It is a duplicate that Trevor pointed out. You should cut the download task into buffers, and check after each buffer, if `e.Cancelled`.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to cancel an arbitrary task from the outside.

Fortunately, `WebClient` allows cancellation (although for some reason, it doesn't simply take a `CancellationToken` the way it should): simply call `WebClient.CancelAsync()` whenever you want to cancel a pending asynchronous operation.

If you want to wrap this functionality using a `CancellationToken`, you can do something like this:

```
Task DownloadFileTaskAsync(this WebClient client, string address, string filename, 
                           CancellationToken token)
{
  token.Register(() => client.CancelAsync());

  return client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(address, filename);
}
```