# How can I stop/cancel a copy procedure in C#

Tags: c#, file

I want to provide and implement a kind of stop mechanism to the following copy files/folders procedure by a click button event. :

```
private void btnCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Copy(sourceDirectory, targetDirectory);
    }

public static void Copy(string sourceDirectory, string targetDirectory)
    {
        DirectoryInfo diSource = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirectory);
        DirectoryInfo diTarget = new DirectoryInfo(targetDirectory);

        CopyAll(diSource, diTarget);
    }
public static void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
    {
        // Copy each file into the new directory.
        foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles())
        {
            fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.FullName, fi.Name), true);
        }

        // Copy each subdirectory using recursion.
        foreach (DirectoryInfo diSourceSubDir in source.GetDirectories())
        {
            DirectoryInfo nextTargetSubDir =
                target.CreateSubdirectory(diSourceSubDir.Name);
            CopyAll(diSourceSubDir, nextTargetSubDir);
        }
    }
private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
            //A way to stop CopyAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target) execution
   }
```

and I have no ideea how to do this. Any hints please?

Comment: Since the copy operation is running on the UI thread you don't have any way to click the stop button. You first need to move the copying into its own thread (and then you can use a `CancellationToken`)

Comment: A cancellation pattern is readily available through the `Task` class. Basically, you  move your operation in a `Task` (which is a good thing, because it willavoid blocking your UI as it currently is) and use a CancellationToken. You can activate the CacnellationToken from a button.

Comment: See another potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115836/cancel-async-task-from-a-button