# Cancel a fuction/process

Tags: c#, winforms

I currently have a application that pings  a list of IPs.
The user clicks a button and it continuously pings all IPS for 20 seconds..
What I want to do is click a button to stop this.

I created a function i called "Process" and it calls this process when the button is clicked.

I tried to create a bool value and while loop for when it's false and made the stop button change the bool value to true, but it doesn't seem to stop anything, in fact I can't even close the window until the ping is completed.

My code is below.

```
private bool _stopLoop;

    private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process();
    }

private void Process()
{
    while (_stopLoop == false)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dataGridView1Row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                var count = 20;
                progressBar1.Value = i * progressBar1.Maximum / count;
                Application.DoEvents();
                var url = dataGridView1Row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                int timeout = 500;
                Ping ping = new Ping();

                PingReply pingreply = ping.Send(url, timeout);
                PingReply result = null;
                IPStatus status;

                result = pingreply;
                status = result.Status;

                if (status != IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    dataGridView1Row.Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    dataGridView1Row.Cells[0].Value = "Offline";
                }
                else
                {
                    dataGridView1Row.Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    dataGridView1Row.Cells[0].Value = "Online";
                }



            }
        }
    }
}

private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  _stopLoop = true;
}
```

Comment: You need to separate your ping logic from the user interface. You can look at Threading or more simply to a BackgroundWorker component

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115836/cancel-async-task-from-a-button

Comment: Your loop doesn't give the 2nd button a chance. To do things for a timespane use a Timer!

Comment: @ErikAllen your poblem is how you set up the loops. 1st, you run over all ```rows``` which i guess are your IP's and ping them, then the next outer loop is  saying, do that 20 times, then the last most outer loop says, do that until you say stop. once you hit cancel, you also need to break out of the 2 inner loops over the rows as well as over your 20 repititions

Comment: Apart from that, you really should create a Background Task for something like that.

Comment: A prime use case for `async`/`await`.

Comment: There are numerous bad practices here but the big ones are use of `DoEvents` and use of high latency synchronous operations on a UI thread. As Alejandro alludes, you would do much, much better to delete the `DoEvents` entirely and thereby avoid re-entrancy, and change the blocking operations to asynchronous operations.  Let the compiler handle orchestrating the asynchronous workflow; avoiding code like this is why we invented async workflows in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am only targeting the direct questions why the loops dont stop. Implementing a background thread or tasks or background worker is a better solution but not the question :)

As in my comment states, you only break out of your "infinite" loop which is the most outer loop.

The two inner loops which run over your IP's ( `foreach (DataGridViewRow dataGridView1Row in dataGridView1.Rows){ [...] }`  as well as your "do it for 20 times" loops `for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){ [...] }` need to be broken out of if you want it to stop.

this means you can change them like that:

```cs
while (_stopLoop == false)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {   
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dataGridView1Row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if(_stopLoop)
                 return; // finish execution and jump out of all loops, or use break to jump into the for loop, but then you need to break out of it as well
             
            /* your ping logic */

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works exactly how I needed it too. Thank you!

Comment: Still consider that currently you executing this in the UI thread, only because you use ```Application.DoEvents()``` you can interact with the UI otherwise it would freeze. Consider one of the alternate solutions as well like a background worker, threads or tasks :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you use async/await your GUI can be responsive and your requests can be concurrent at the same time:

```
private CancellationTokenSource pingCancellation;

private async void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const int pingTimeout = 500;
    var pingDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);

    btnPlay.Enabled = false;
    dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;

    var entries =
        dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                          .Where(r => !r.IsNewRow)
                          .Select(row => new { Row = row, Hostname = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), Ping = new Ping() })
                          .ToList();


    pingCancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
    pingCancellation.Token.Register(() => entries.ForEach(e => e.Ping.SendAsyncCancel()));

    btnStop.Enabled = true;

    pingCancellation.CancelAfter(pingDuration);
    var finishTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(pingDuration);
    try
    {
        while (!pingCancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(entries.Select(async e =>
            {
                var result = await e.Ping.SendPingAsync(e.Hostname, pingTimeout);

                if (result.Status != IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    e.Row.Cells[0].Value = "Offline";
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    e.Row.Cells[0].Value = "Online";
                }
            }).Concat(new[] { Task.Delay(pingTimeout, pingCancellation.Token) /*Rate limiting*/ }));

            progressBar1.Value = (int)Math.Min(progressBar1.Maximum * (pingDuration - (finishTime - DateTime.UtcNow)).Ticks / pingDuration.Ticks, progressBar1.Maximum);
        }
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
    }

    btnStop.Enabled = false;
    pingCancellation.Dispose();
    pingCancellation = null;
    foreach (var entry in entries)
    {
        entry.Ping.Dispose();
    }
    progressBar1.Value = 0;
    dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
    btnPlay.Enabled = true;
}

private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pingCancellation != null && !pingCancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        pingCancellation.Cancel();
    }
}
```